# MySQL how get users who are not my friends

Tags: mysql

could someone help me, I need to get users who are not my friends
I have the following tables

**users**

| id | `user` |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 |
| 2 | name2 |

and the table **friends**:

| id | `id_user` | `id_friends` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 4 |

I try something like that, but in some queries it returns the ones that I already have added

```
Select  u.*
from    users u left join friends f
          on f.id_user = 2 
          and f.id_friends = u.id
where  u.id <> 2
and    f.id_friend is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using NOT EXISTS to return all users not already "friended". That includes users not already in the `friends` table.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM   users u 
WHERE  u.id <> 2
AND    NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT NULL
       FROM   friends f 
       WHERE ( f.id_friend = u.id AND f.id_user = 2 )
       OR    ( f.id_friend = 2 AND f.id_user = u.id )

)
```

**Results:**

> ```
> id | user 
> -: | :----
>  1 | Name1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=445254aca922859bf417343b74f19791)*

Comment: if it works but it only hides the id of the third column

Comment: Not sure what you mean?  "users who are not my friends" should not be based on the `friends` table.

Comment: to give me a better understanding, for example if my f.id_user = 2 it hides id 3, but if f.id_user = 3 it doesn't hide id 2

Comment: Oh, right!  This should fix that https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=445254aca922859bf417343b74f19791